# Unable to resolve drawable

Tags: android, drawable, imagebutton

I am trying to add images to an image button.
My button.xml looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" />
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" />
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" />
</selector>
```

And my main.xml looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageButton
        android:src="@drawable/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And my error looks like so:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:151)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:749)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:695)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:145)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:662)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:113)
at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:51)
at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:47)
```

I understand that the error is focused on the first "item" tag in the button.xml. I have tried changing src to background in the main.xml, I have tried changing drawable to background in the button.xml but I get the same error every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using an ordinary button instead of an imageButton?
Like:

```
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Awesome, simply awesome. Thank you sir or madam.

Comment: That's sir :). No problem, but please mark the answer as accepted if it resolved your issue.

Comment: It won't let me do so without a rep of 15 :(

Comment: I think you can always mark the answers to your own questions as accepted. Up/down voting requires some rep on the other hand. But if it doesn't seem to work, never mind :)